# Activate sheet when clicking on cell based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I was attempting to set up a way to jump to sheets in the same workbook by clicking on a cell and activating the sheet with the same value.  My code works when the cell value is text. However, it does not work when the value is a number.  The majority (99%) of the sheets will be only numbers (6 digits) for the sheet name.  An example of a sheet name would be 110110.  Here is my code I used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B800")) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Value <> "" Then
Sheets(Target.Value).Activate
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

I receive:
Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range

whenever I click on the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, you can refer to a [sheet by the name or index](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/refer-to-sheets-by-inadex-number).

In your case, you are referring by index (number) that does not exist in the Excel.
You can simple convert the number to string by using CStr():

```
Sheets(CStr(Target.Value)).Activate
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it right away!